# Orthogonal complement of polynomials with coefficients summing up to 0

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Consider the vector subspace of polynomials with coefficients summing up to $0$. I am trying to show that its orthogonal complement is $\{ 0 \}$. I have read through Disintegrating by Parts' interpretation found here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1017851/966646

Can anyone walk me through why the vector subspace of polynomials with coefficients summing up to $0$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: The linked answer considers a particular subspace of $L^2[0,1]$, which is a specific vector space with a specific inner product. Are you interested in the exact same context?  (The choice of ambient space and inner product does matter; "polynomials with coefficients summing up to $0$" is not enough to specify this information)  If so, where do you encounter difficulty with the solution?

Comment: What inner product and space are being considered here?

Comment: I am interested in the same set up as. As for the solution, I guess I just did not find it intuitive. Its a good solution but I was wondering if there is a more intuitive solution that calls upon the inner product.

Comment: $L^2[0,1]$ with its inner product.

Comment: What about it is unintuitive?

Comment: How can we conclude from the fact that the set of polynomials are dense in $L^2[0,1]$ that the orthogonal complement is $\{ 0 \}$. Also I guess  I was looking for a proof by definition.

Comment: If the polynomials are dense then for any $f \in L^2[0,1] $,  $ f = \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n$ where $ p_n$ is a sequence polynomials. If $g$ is any function orthogonal to all of $\{p_n \}$ then $\langle f, g\rangle  =  \lim \langle p_n,g \rangle = 0 $. So $g$ would be orthogonal to all of $L^2[0,1] $. This means $g = 0$.

Comment: and $g$ being orthogonal to all of $L^2[0,1]$ would imply that $g = 0$, which then tell us that the orthogonal complement has to be $\{0 \}$ ?

Comment: Yes ... If $g$ was orthogonal to all $L^2[0,1] $ , it's orthogonal to itself so $||g|| = 0 $. This means $g = 0 $ by axioms.

Comment: Got it! That makes sense. Thank you. If possible could you show me why these polynomials are dense in $L^2[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polynomials are dense in $L^2[0,1]$. Now given a polynomial, say $p(t)$ of degree $n$ and the sum of its coefficients equal to $P$ one can find another polynomial, say $q(t)$ of the form $q(t) = p(t) -Pt^m$ which has sum of coefficients $0$. If $m$ is large enough, $L^2$ difference between $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ can be made arbitrary small.
In words, polynomials with coefficients summing up to $0$ are dense in $L^2[0,1]$.